# How to add Jquery-ui to textbox ? In tag-it function

Tags: c#, asp.net, tags

I want to use jquery-ui tagit function in my web page in a textbox. I did homework and a lot of research, the final code I got is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mytags").tagit();
    });
</script>
```

The Problem is I want the inputfield (textbox) to be like the normal size of textbox but this code is showing a inputfield wider as long as the web page. Here is what is is looking like : http://screencast.com/t/XD7PaAkMj  I have tried a lot to apply this to the texbox but then too its size is not decreasing.

Please help me with this.

Thanks,

Edward

Comment: May be some `css ` related issue have you applied any `css ` for your `text box` or `div`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the height and width on the ul.tagit css selector? For example:

```
ul.tagit {
height:30px;
width:30px
}
```

Comment: Hi JP can you please tell me where should I put this above code ?

Comment: There are a number of ways. Typically you would include your CSS in an external file. The following document should help: http://www.webstartcenter.com/howto/css_inc.php